# Why only css files are displayed while inspecting an element?

Tags: css, sass, element

First when I used to inspect element in the chrome browser during web development, It used to display the exact `scss` (css pre-processor)file in which those styles are present. It was very helpful. But now When I inspect an element it is showing only the computed `css` file. I can't exactly figure out what has happened to my browser. Should any settings be changed? kindly suggest a solution.

Answer (score 0):

You're probably missing the source map file (`.map`)

From **[Chrome Devtools Docs](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/css-preprocessors)**:

> For preprocessors that support CSS source maps, DevTools lets you
>   live-edit your preprocessor source files in the Sources panel, and
>   view the results without having to leave DevTools or refresh the page.
>   When you inspect an element whose styles are provided by a generated
>   CSS file, the Elements panel displays a link to the original source
>   file, not the generated .css file.

Check if Chrome has the featured enabled:

> CSS source maps are enabled by default. You can choose to enable
>   automatic reloading of generated CSS files.
>
> **To enable CSS source maps and CSS reload:**
>
> 1. Open DevTools Settings and click General.
> 2. Turn on Enable CSS source maps and Auto-reload generated CSS.

Most modern IDEs which support SCSS also generate the map files, check your IDE settings to make sure the files are created each time you compile your SCSS code.

```
style.scss compiles into:
|_ style.css
|_ style.css.map
```

Comment: I Enabled css source maps. unable to find the option `Auto-reload generated CSS`. And I checked and the` style.css.map` file does exist. My problem is First the exact `scss` file is shown. But when I change a style of an element in the editor then all files are being converted to `css` files.